# Is there any way to retrieve labels or folder ID in IMAP MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

I am using MailKit IMAP to retrieve messages from Email Server(GMail). I have to cached these messages into my local system so that user can access messages Offline.Currently I am getting all folders or labels that Email Server has.But I do not get label ID or folder ID that is correspond to each message.I have read Google Gmail API that says each label or folder has ID and one or more labels can be applied on a single message e.g a message may be in Inbox as well as in Personal labels.I just want to know how many labels are applied on a single message and what are the IDs of these labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from `folder.Fetch (range, MessageSummaryItems.GMailLabels);`

Comment: But it only return label's name associated with message.I need to sync my local server 's labels with IMAP server labels in case of any changes happened with labels(suppose we rename labels on IMAP server). How to track these changes.or Is there any other way to track the changes.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to track that with gmail via IMAP.